# How can I search within a Podio App using PodioKit and PKTSearchAPI?

Tags: objective-c, swift, podio

I'm trying to do a simple query within all items in a Podio app. But I don't understand how to access the results of the search request. Here's what I have:

```
    let query = PKTSearchQuery.init(text: "search term")
    let search = PKTSearchAPI.requestToSearchInAppWithID(1234567, query: query, offset: 0, limit: 30)
```

`requestToSearchInAppWithID` creates a `PKTRequest` object so it seems something needs to be returned via a `PKTResponse` object. I understand that everything in PodioKit is asynchronous and the examples given [here](http://podio.github.io/podio-objc/async/) for Objective-C and [here](http://podio.github.io/podio-objc-platform/async/) for Swift make it clear how responses are received using `onComplete`, `onSuccess`, `onError` completion blocks, but `PKTSearchAPI` seems to lack a completion block.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The completion blocks you noted from the documentation are accessible on any `PKTAsyncTask`

To retrieve a `PKTAsyncTask` given a `PKTRequest` object, you can use the `performRequest` method of `PKTClient`.  For example, the following snippet will execute your search request, and then print the results to the console:

```
let query = PKTSearchQuery.init(text: "search term")
let search = PKTSearchAPI.requestToSearchInAppWithID(1234567, query: query, offset: 0, limit: 30)

let searchTask = PKTClient.currentClient().performRequest(search)

searchTask.onComplete { [weak self] response, error in
  let body = response.body as! [String: AnyObject]
  let items = body["results"] as? [[NSObject:AnyObject]]

  for item in items! {
    print("Search result \(item["rank"]!) title: \(item["title"]!)")
  }
}
```

Edit: For additional information about the data you can expect in the search response, see the [Podio API Docs for Search](https://developers.podio.com/doc/search/search-in-space-22479)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I never would have figured it out on my own. I wonder why there isn't a `PKTSearch` that returns `PKTAsyncTask` directly.